# @ngrx/effects dispatch action again

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I'm new at ngrx/store and effects so I still don't understand the flow of a dispatched action :

1. actions -> effect -> reducer -> store
2. actions -> reducer -> effect -> reducer -> store

my problem is when I call `store.select()` I find that the action is dispatched two times and this is what I did for test :

> Reducer function

```
switch (action.type) { 
  ...
  default: { 
    console.log('In reducer function'); 
    return state; 
  }
}
```

> Effects class constructor

```
constructor( private action$: Actions ) { 
  console.log('in effect constructor'); 
}
```

> and this what I get in the console

```
In reducer function
in effect constructor
In reducer function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to log in reducer not only a message but `action.type` then you could see that it has 2 different actions: `store init` and `effects init`.

When you dispatch an `action` it goes first to `effects`, then it goes to a `reducer` and the `reducer` can update a related `state`.

usually people dispatch a load action, it is handled in an effect, effect loads data and returns a success action with payload, then a reducer receives the success action and sets the payload to its state.